# Obtener usuarios con puntos entre 0-10, 11-20... MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

Necesito obtener de una base de datos de `mongo` los usuarios que sus puntos van de `0-10`, `11-20`, `21-30`... así hasta `100` puntos.
El campo puntos es de tipo string.
La idea final es obtener algo similar a esto:

```
0-10.
Usuario :554545    Puntos:1.
Usuario :111154    Puntos:7.
11-20.
Usuario :554545    Puntos:15.
Usuario :554545    Puntos:18.

Etc...
```

Necesito hacer pruebas en `Robo3T` pero la idea de la query será para asociarla a un batch (en java) que consultará la base de datos y sacará el resultado en un fichero.

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

intenta con esto, asi se hacen las consultas de rangos...

De esta forma buscas los menores o iguales:

```
                            inclue el cero y exclue el 11 = 0-10
db.nombreBD.find({ puntos: { $lt: 0, $gte: 11 }, type: "Usuario" })

db.nombreBD.find({ puntos: { $lt: 11, $gte: 21 }, type: "Usuario" })
```

De esta forma buscas los solo menores:

```
db.nombreBD.find({ puntos: { $lte: 10 } })
```

Te dejo el [link](http://www.happyminds.es/filtros-de-busqueda-en-mongodb/#sthash.ROCqGGwm.dpbs) que te puede ayudar mucho mas

Comment: Esa es la idea que tenía ,pero hacer esas consultas por cada rango es lo que no sabría, eso y que luego me muestre el usuario y los puntos ordenados, primeros los del rango 0-10, después 11-20, etc.

Comment: Además que los campos son de tipo string y no puedo comparar si son mayores o menores porque no son numéricos.

Comment: Hubiera empezado por ahi, ya que no se pueden comparar estrings entre rangos, te tocaria por cada numero un comparacion y no seria eficiente, por ende tocaria que cambiaras los formatos de los campos de la BD

Comment: De igual modo, si fueran números , cómo podría hacer lo que le comentaba anteriormente?

Comment: lo que quieres es sacar todos los rango en una sola consulta >?

Comment: Sí, algo como lo que puse en la descripción, como que vaya agrupando por rango a los usuarios y así después mostrar su id y los puntos